# Problem with my program for getting only letters (upper and lower case)

Tags: python, string, integer

I'm trying to write a script which asks a user for input and validates the input in a loop, but I'm getting the error: `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`.

I've tried a `while` and a `for` loop. Even without loop and just with an `if` and an `else`.

Here's what I have so far:

```
def majuscule(word):
    for j in word:
        if (chr(j) >=  chr(0)) and (chr(j) <= chr(64)) and (chr(j) >= chr(91)) and (chr(j) <= chr(96)) and (chr(j) >= chr(123)):
           word = input("What's your word ?")
        else:
            print('Valide word')
```

Comment: What is a valid word according to you? Lower, Upper etc.

Comment: just a word with lower and upper case letter

Comment: The reason you are getting a `TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` is because you are going through the letters of the word and passing them to `chr()`, which only accepts an integer, not a letter. `chr()` converts an ASCII numeric code into a letter; you already have the letter in the case of the input, so there is no `chr()` conversion necessary on it.

Be sure to upvote the answers that work for you and pick an accepted answer -- thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To check if a word is just letters or not, use the in-built python function of `isalpha()`

```
def majuscule(word):

    if word.isalpha():
          
        print('Valide word')

    else:
        
        word = input("What's your word ?")
```

Remember that `isalpha()` only returns `True` for alphabets, even if there is a 'space', it returns `False`

Answer (score 0):

You can use functions `islower()` and `isupper()` per symbol.
You did not provide examples to your problem so I don't understand exactly what you're looking for but telling if symbol is upper per char you can use something like this

```
def majuscule(word):
    for symbol in word:
        if symbol.islower():
           print(f"{symbol} is lower cased")
        elif symbol.isupper():
           print(f"{symbol} is upper cased"
        else:
            print("Symbol {symbol} is neither upper cased nor lower cased")
```